# Logging HTTP requests and responses in quarkus resteasy

Tags: httprequest, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I am running into a problem with calling a REST endpoint on a server, using a REST client in Quarkus, built with the org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.RestClientBuilder. I would very much like to debug the service, by writing the HTTP requests and responses to the log, so I might see what is actually being sent to the server. The hunt for a guide for that particular issue has eluded me however.
I managed to build a logging filter but that only logs out the URL and the Entitys toString value, which is not at all the same as the HTTP request and response being sent.
Help me by pointing me to a solution to log the actual HTTP request and response.

Answer (score 22):

If you are using resteasy reactive you can turn on logging with:

```
quarkus.rest-client.logging.scope=request-response
quarkus.rest-client.logging.body-limit=1024
quarkus.log.category."org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.logging".level=DEBUG
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me, when using a rest client within Quarkus to call out to another http server - and I want to log that request/response
BTW docs are here: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive#logging-traffic

Answer (score 20):

You can try to enable the logging for all the traffic including wire or just some components, here in the [logging configuration guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#runtime-configuration) you can find how enable just some components logging.

Add this to your application.properties and you should be able to see some logging information `quarkus.log.category."org.apache.http".level=DEBUG`

If you need to log everything you can always put quarkus in debug level ALL, and the pick the components you need to constraint the logging, whit this you see all the traces at wire level.

You can also enable the http access log with this [guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#configuring-http-access-logs)

Good luck.

Comment: "org.apache.http.wire" just shows the requests and responses.

Comment: The guide at the bottom is what helped me, I ended up using: quarkus.http.access-log.enabled=true

Answer (score 4):

Check this: https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#the-jax-rs-way

Simply implement that class and you will start logging. Like this:

```
@Provider
class LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter,
    ContainerResponseFilter {

    /* Useful stuff for later development purposes.
    @Context
    UriInfo info;

    @Context
    HttpServerRequest request;
    */

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        Log.info(requestContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, 
                       ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
        Log.info(responseContext);
    }
}
```

Then you may use UriInfo, HttpServerRequest and ContainerRequestContext to get any data you want and add to your custom log.

---

Another easier approach, which may be sufficient:

Add these configs do your application.properties.

```
quarkus.rest-client.logging.scope=request-response
quarkus.rest-client.logging.body-limit=5000
```

quarkus.log.category."org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.logging".level=DEBUG

Reference: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive#logging-traffic