# How to log HTTP request and response body?

Tags: quarkus

How do I log the request and response bodies on a RestEasy Reactive endpoint?

For example, if I have an endpoint like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Uni<MyEntity> create(CreateMyEntityDTO dto) {
    return myService.create(dto);
}
```

How do I log the request payload and response body?

I've been browsing about this for a while. There's even some related threads on StackOverflow and issues on GitHub, but it's still not clear to me how this is done. Is it just a matter of configuration? Do I need to write a request filter? Maybe using some sort of plugin?

What I have right now is this configuration to enable HTTP logs, but it only logs the request endpoint and response status. I really need to log the payload.

```
quarkus.http.access-log.enabled=true
```

Comment: this is a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165663/logging-http-requests-and-responses-in-quarkus-resteasy